# Good Style of Haskell Fibonacci Function

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function, fibonacci

I am just learning Haskell and tried implementing a function for getting a list containing the first N fibonacci numbers:

```
fibonacci :: Integer -> [Integer]
fibonacci 1 = [0]
fibonacci 2 = fibonacci 1 ++ [1]
fibonacci n = appendSumOfLastTwo (fibonacci (n - 1))

appendSumOfLastTwo :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
appendSumOfLastTwo xs = xs ++ [addLastTwo xs]

addLastTwo :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
addLastTwo xs = last xs + (xs !! ((length xs) - 2))
```

This works but is not really pretty since it requires two helper functions with weird names. Is it common in Haskell to have such singularly used functions?

To get rid of these functions I tried anonymous functions:

```
fibonacci :: Integer -> [Integer]
fibonacci 1 = [0]
fibonacci 2 = fibonacci 1 ++ [1]
fibonacci n = (\xs -> xs ++ [(\xs -> last xs + (xs !! ((length xs) - 2))) xs]) (fibonacci ( n - 1))
```

But that is not really much better since its almost completely unreadable.

What would you guys think? How could I structure my code the best?

Comment: while I personally enjoy this kind of questions (and it did provoke some good answers) sadly those are not really a good fit for SO - see you don't really have a problem, you are asking for advice or and code review and I think the codereview site on StackExchange might indeed be a better place for those

Comment: Oh well, okay. Thank you, I will post such questions there next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps use the `let` keyword. It allows you to bind variables (including functions) that will only be in scope for the expression:

```
> let x = 3 in x + 2
5
```

Here `x` is bound to three before `x + 2` is evaluated, giving five.

You can do something similar with your example:

```
fibonacci :: Integer -> [Integer]
fibonacci 1 = [0]
fibonacci 2 = fibonacci 1 ++ [1]
fibonacci n = let
  addLastTwo :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
  addLastTwo xs = last xs + (xs !! ((length xs) - 2))

  appendSumOfLastTwo :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
  appendSumOfLastTwo xs = xs ++ [addLastTwo xs]
 in appendSumOfLastTwo (fibonacci (n - 1))
```

Let's see if we can do better. We can also use `where` as syntactic sugar to improve readability. This keyword behaves exactly like `let ... in ...` except if you have a lot of variables to bind and a relatively short expression, it may be more readable:

```
fibonacci :: Integer -> [Integer]
fibonacci 1 = [0]
fibonacci 2 = fibonacci 1 ++ [1]
fibonacci n = appendSumOfLastTwo (fibonacci (n - 1))
  where
    addLastTwo :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
    addLastTwo xs = last xs + (xs !! ((length xs) - 2))

    appendSumOfLastTwo :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
    appendSumOfLastTwo xs = xs ++ [addLastTwo xs]
```

OK, there is definitely room for improvement here. We are still not "thinking with portals" with respect to how to approach some of our functions. In particular, `addLastTwo` can be significantly improved with pattern matching:

```
addLastTwo :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
addLastTwo (x:y:[]) = x + y
addLastTwo (_:rest) = addLastTwo rest
addLastTwo _ = error "List has less than two elements!"
```

This reduces the number of iterations of the list down to one from three (one for `last`, one for `length`, and up to one for `!!`).

Furthermore, it's much easier to append to the head of a list than it is to append to the end of it. You can always `reverse` the list if necessary. Anytime you write `list ++ [elem]` think about whether or not you actually mean `elem : list`.

With that in mind, and a bit more pattern matching, a relatively clean version of your algorithm would look something like this:

```
fibonacci :: Integer -> [Integer]
fibonacci 1 = [0]
fibonacci 2 = [0, 1]
fibonacci n = reverse $ (x + y) : upToN
  where
    upToN@(x:y:_) = reverse $ fibonacci (n - 1)
```

Here, the `@` character binds a variable to a pattern. In the example above, `upToN` will be bound to the list `[x, y, ...]`, but also `x` and `y` will be in scope.

I suggest you also take some time to see why @karakfa's answer works, and why it would be faster than the approach you've taken.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. This is exactly what I was hoping for. Seeing the eolution of my initial code taught me quite a lot.

Comment: Oh, man, those two reverses... it would be much better to have a Fibonacci function that simply returns the answers in the other order. If necessary, call it `fibonacci'` and write `fibonacci = reverse . fibonacci'` so that you only get one reverse per call to `fibonacci` instead of two reverses for every element in the result.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get prettier than this

```
fibs = 1:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

and use as for any n

```
take n fibs
```

Or, if you want to implement from basics, perhaps better to define n'th Fibonacci number first

```
fib 1 = 1
fib 2 = 1                                      
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

and the series will be simply

```
map fib [1..n]
```

notice that the performance will be terrible for any large n.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution but I was rather looking for a cleaner way of implementing my algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps closest to your original design, but with linear performance, is to use `iterate` with a pair of numbers as the state:

```
almostFibs :: [(Integer, Integer)]
almostFibs = iterate (\(x, y) -> (y, x + y)) (0, 1)
```

This gives you a pair of "previous" and "current" values:

```
Prelude> take 10 almostFibs
[(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(5,8),(8,13),(13,21),(21,34),(34,55)]
```

To really get `fibs`, you just drop the "previous" value:

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = map snd almostFibs
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the helper functions, which are perfectly valid. It is certainly common to have such functions, and especially to just define them locally. It is with the list indexing and having to deal with the end of the list where the problem lies. If you really need these operations, then a list is the wrong data structure.

The concept of retrieving the "last" two items in the list and adding them is perfectly sound - you just have to deal with the front of the list, and reverse it at the end. So "last" becomes "first" and you just pattern match.

```
fibonacci :: Integer -> [Integer]
fibonacci = reverse . fib where
  fib n | n < 1 = [] 
  fib 1 = [0]
  fib 2 = [1,0] 
  fib n = case fib (n-1) of 
            r@(a:b:_) -> a+b:r
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most idiomatic approach would be to generate the infinite list and then take the first `n` elements, as others have suggested.

Otherwise, generating the *reversed* sequence of the first `n` fibonacci numbers also looks fine. This allows to add "a number at the end of the list" by simply prepending a new element.

If instead we prefer to generate the list in the direct order, we could use a recursion as follows:

```
fibonacci :: Int -> [Int]
fibonacci n = fib 0 1 n
   where fib _ _ 0 = []
         fib a b n = a : fib b (a+b) (n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to use Haskell's lazy evaluation and generate an infinite list. You can then `take` how every many numbers you want from that list.

```
fibonacci :: [Integer]
fibonacci = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibonacci
```

Once you have this function, you can retrieve how ever many elements `n` that you need.

```
> take 7 fibonacci
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
```